# python load dict data to csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary file I want to load to a csv file where the key is my column, and value will keep appending to new row each time new data reads in.
My code:

```
with open ('master_result.csv','r+b')as csvFile:
    header = next(csv.reader(csvFile))
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile,header, 0)
    dict_writer.writerow(dict1)
```

but I get

```
header = next(csv.reader(csvFile)
StopIteration
```

I can not find the issue.

Comment: Are you sure `master_result.csv` is not empty?

Comment: Why are you both reading and writing in the same file?  What does the file contain before the program starts?  When it ends?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is throwing a [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) error because there are no further values in your iterable (i.e., your file).

One way you could address this is by implementing some [error handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

```
with open ('master_result.csv','r+b') as csvFile:
    try:
        # check if the necessary headers exist in your 
        # csvFile already.
        header = next(csv.reader(csvFile))
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, header)
        dict_writer.writerow(dict1)
    except StopIteration:
        # If the headers don't already exist, 
        # use the keys of Dict1 to establish them.
        header = dict1.keys()
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, header)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerow(dict1) 

# 'master_result.csv' output if dict1 = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3}:
# key1    key2    key3
# value1  value2  value3
```

You could also wrap your `with` block with a `for` loop to iterate through multiple dictionaries (e.g., a list of dicts) and include all of the values in your output file.  It's just a guess, but I think this is what you mean by:

> ...and value will keep appending to new row each time new data reads in.